# How can I print the first 2 maximum values in a database column using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How can I print the first two maximum values under an attribute (column) in a database table using SQL?

I have a column named `salary` that contains different rows, (approximately 10 rows). We need to print out the first two maximum values.

I know we can get the first maximum value by using `max` function, but what can I do if I need the first two values?

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL, which is it? Make up your mind

Comment: If you have like 1000, 1000, 900 in your table, then you need the 1000, 1000 as output or 1000 and 900.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this? (mysql)

```
select `salary` from `mytable` order by `salary` desc limit 2
```

As per Alex's answer, you can add the `distinct` keyword to ensure that you get two different values.

```
select distinct `salary` from `mytable` order by `salary` desc limit 2
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 2 salary
from table
order by salary desc
```

In MySQL

```
SELECT salary
from table
order by salary desc
limit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct salary from mytable order by salary desc limit 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok If you need only the two top, even if the are equal, the others have rigth, but if you need the top 2 number (and you don't care if there are multiple instance from them) you can use this:

```
SELECT 
Salary 
FROM Salaries
GROUP BY Salary
ORDER BY Salary DESC
LIMIT 2
```